# Creating a matrix of strings/classes that sklearn will accept

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to preprocess my data text data for sklearn so I can create a classifier that can differentiate between two classes. I have my data, and it's split into two arrays of strings.

```
X2 = oneAthleteComments
X = zeroAthleteComments
```

And the count vectorizer code from sklearn works on each individually...

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
X2_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X2)
```

All I need to do is bring the arrays X and X2 together with the classes into a matrix in order to place that into the countVectorizer, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting that working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do these strings represent? Are they documents? Why are there two arrays?

Comment: The strings are comments for a player. I'm trying to figure out if a specific player will get selected for a team based on their comments.

There are two arrays because there were two documents that came in, those players that didn't get selected and those that did. The oneAthleteComments array has all of the comments for athletes that got selected, and the zeroAthleteComments have comments for athletes that didn't get selected.

Comment: Did you try good old `fit_transform(X + X2)`?